# Написание сайта. Как добавить кнопку(popup) в левую часть по середине не зависимо от блоков которые у меня есть

Tags: html, css

У меня сайт как по блокам. header, основная часть, footer. Если я прописываю код для popup в нем то получается как на фото под цифрой 3. Если прописываю ниже основной части, то есть отдельно вообще, то получается как под цифрой 1. А нужно сделать так чтобы было под цифрой 2. То есть отдельно от Всего блока по центру. Мне надо сбоку сделать такую стрелочку, и когда я на нее нажимаю появляется окно. Это у меня получилось, но как сделать так чтобы эта кнопка была под цифрой 2. Если что под кнопкой я подразумеваю текст "Вызвать всплывающее окно" на фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно абсолютно спозиционировать окно относительно body

Comment: Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для демонстрации нажмите на кнопочку.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.target.classList.toggle('position-left');
});
```

```css
body {
height: 200vh;
}

div {
width: 70vw;
height: 70vh;
background: #ccc;
margin-left: 15vw;
margin-top: 15vh;
}

button {
width: 25vw;
height: 30vh;
font-size: 20pt;
}

button.position-left {
position:fixed;
left: 0;
top:50vh;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Toggle me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: куда нужно добавить этот фрагмент кода "document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.target.classList.toggle('position-left');
});"

И даже так, тут на сайте я пробую запустить "выполнить код" по верх кнопки с фоном какая-то хрень, проверьте сами. В этом окне которое закрывает основную часть - ошибка

Comment: JS,  приложенный к ответу, только подключает и отключает у кнопки класс из CSS `.position-left`. JS вам вообще не нужен. Нужно только содержание класса CSS.

Comment: все равно не получается, вот страница с html, css и js 
https://jsfiddle.net/LolKekChebyrek/s8m4r162/#&togetherjs=efgFoQJ3qd
Поможешь?

Comment: @Jenka https://jsfiddle.net/5ktj6br4/1/ так?

Comment: да, спасибо большое, выручил очень

Comment: @Jenka Сделал вам еще работающие без JavaScript вкладки https://jsfiddle.net/kb35odu9/